# Is ValueExpression threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, el

In my project I'm using standalone jasper implementation of EL. I added libs to my maven pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.32</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.32</version>
    </dependency>
```

Currently my app is very slow because of heavy usage of el expressions - it's compiling right in time it should be invoked.
Now I want to move expression compilation in initialization time but I wonder if it will be threadsafe to use same ValueExpression's in multiple threads. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value expresion are not thread-safe. However, an EL implementation should cache parsed expressions internally and calling `ExpressionFactory.createExpression(...)` should need to parse an expression string only at first time.

Depending on your environment, you may want to try an EL implementation that performs better than Tomcat's, e.g. [JUEL](http://juel.sf.net) could improve performance significantly.

Comment: Also I found information from [JUEL site](http://juel.sourceforge.net/guide/util/index.html) useful:
  
At creation time, the context's function mapper and variable mapper are used to bind function invocations to static methods and identifiers (variables) to value expressions. The context's resolver is not used at creation time.
At evaluation time, the context's resolver is used for property resolutions and to resolve unbound identifiers (top-level properties). The context's function mapper and variable mapper are not used at evaluation time.

Answer (score 0):

Don;t think so unless you take care of thread safety issue in the common initialization code.